# Android firestore could not reach backend error in react native

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native

I have been looking for the solution about this issue, but I couldn't find it until now.

It is such a weird issue.
I tried with **react-native 0.56.0** at first, it compiles well, and then this error is occured on the android device.

> firestore(5.5.0) could not reach backend
>   However, the problem is that the error doesn't happen to android simulator. It only happens to android device. (It's really weird)

So, I tried with **react-native 0.57.1** in this time, then this error occured.
And it's printed that The development server returned response error code: 500 on android device screen.

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `schedule/tracking` from `/Users/jeonmingyu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js`: Module `schedule/tracking` does not exist in the Haste module map
>
> This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
>   To resolve try the following:
>     1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
>     2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
>     3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
>     4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
>       at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/jeonmingyu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:209:1301)
>       at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/jeonmingyu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:83:16)
>       at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/jeonmingyu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:238:485)
>       at Object.resolve (/Users/jeonmingyu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:180:25)
>       at dependencies.map.result (/Users/jeonmingyu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:311:29)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at resolveDependencies (/Users/jeonmingyu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:307:16)
>       at /Users/jeonmingyu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:164:33
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (/Users/jeonmingyu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:266:307)

Here's my package.json

**package.json**

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@firebase/firestore": "^0.8.1",
    "firebase": "^5.5.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.2",
    "loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-geocode": "^0.1.2",
    "react-loaders": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.57.0",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^4.0.14",
    "react-native-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-navigation": "^2.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^2.1.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-actions": "^2.4.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.5.7",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.13"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-sass-transformer": "^1.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5"
}
```

If anyone knows about it and has solution, please share your solution.
It drives me crazy! :(